# Java Calculator minus error

Tags: java

I have written this code of calculator.

However, at runtime, if I use the minus button, it becomes plus.
I had tried to delete the code of that plus/minus button but the problem still there.

I have already tried everything, the only useful thing that I found is that the "-" string did not register.

Code:

```
public class Calculator extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    static String OP = "",
              operations = "[+|-|x|/|0|-|.]",
              anw = "noInputYet";
    static float result,
             firstNumber = 0, 
             secondNumber = 0;
    static double prNumber = 0 ;
    static int numberClick = 0;



    private void bt1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        // Button 1 

        if (calScreen.getText().matches(operations)) {
            calScreen.setText("1");}

        else if (result != 0) {
           calScreen.setText("1");
           result = 0;}

        else {
            calScreen.setText(calScreen.getText() + "1");
        }
    }                                   

    private void bt2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        // button 2 
        if (calScreen.getText().matches(operations)) {
            calScreen.setText("2");}

        else if (result != 0) {
           calScreen.setText("2");
           result = 0;}

        else {
            calScreen.setText(calScreen.getText() + "2");
        }
    }                                   

    private void bt3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        // button 3 
        if (calScreen.getText().matches(operations)) {
            calScreen.setText("3");}

        else if (result != 0) {
           calScreen.setText("3");
           result = 0;}

        else {
            calScreen.setText(calScreen.getText() + "3");
        }
    }                                   

    private void bt9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        // button 9
        if (calScreen.getText().matches(operations)) {
            calScreen.setText("9");}

        else if (result != 0) {
           calScreen.setText("9");
           result = 0;}

        else {
            calScreen.setText(calScreen.getText() + "9");
        }
    }                                   

    private void bt8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        // button 8
        if (calScreen.getText().matches(operations)) {
            calScreen.setText("8");}

        else if (result != 0) {
           calScreen.setText("8");
           result = 0;}

        else {
            calScreen.setText(calScreen.getText() + "8");
        }
    }                                   

    private void bt7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        // button 7
        if (calScreen.getText().matches(operations)) {
            calScreen.setText("7");}

        else if (result != 0) {
           calScreen.setText("7");
           result = 0;}

        else {
            calScreen.setText(calScreen.getText() + "7");
        }
    }                                   

    private void bt4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        // button 4
        if (calScreen.getText().matches(operations)) {
            calScreen.setText("4");}

        else if (result != 0) {
           calScreen.setText("4");
           result = 0;}

        else {
            calScreen.setText(calScreen.getText() + "4");
        }
    }                                   

    private void bt5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        // button 5
        if (calScreen.getText().matches(operations)) {
            calScreen.setText("5");}

        else if (result != 0) {
           calScreen.setText("5");
           result = 0;}

        else {
            calScreen.setText(calScreen.getText() + "5");
        }
    }                                   

    private void bt6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        // button 6
        if (calScreen.getText().matches(operations)) {
            calScreen.setText("6");}

        else if (result != 0) {
           calScreen.setText("6");
           result = 0;}

        else {
            calScreen.setText(calScreen.getText() + "6");
        }
    }                                   

    private void btDotActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // button dot 
        if (calScreen.getText().matches(operations)) {
            calScreen.setText("0.");}

        else if (result != 0) {
           calScreen.setText("0.");
           result = 0;}

        else {
            calScreen.setText(calScreen.getText() + ".");
        }
    }                                     

    private void bt0ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        //  button 0
        if (calScreen.getText().matches(operations)) {
            calScreen.setText("0");}

        else if (result != 0) {
           calScreen.setText("0");
           result = 0;}

        else {
            calScreen.setText(calScreen.getText() + "0");
        }

    }                                   

    private void btEqualActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // Result
        secondNumber = Float.parseFloat(calScreen.getText());
        switch(OP){
            case "+" :{
                result = firstNumber +  secondNumber;break;
            }
            case "-":{
                result = firstNumber - secondNumber;break;
            }

            case "*":{
                result = firstNumber * secondNumber;break;
            }
            case "/":{
                result = firstNumber / secondNumber;break;
            }
            default :{
                result = 0 ;break;
            }
        }
        if (result == (int)result){
            calScreen.setText(Integer.toString((int)result));
            anw = Integer.toString((int)result); 
        }//If result is integer
        else {calScreen.setText(Float.toString(result));
              anw = Float.toString(result);
              }// If result is flaot 
        firstNumber= 0;
        secondNumber = 0;
        numberClick = 0;

    }                                       

    private void btPlusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        //Plus button
        firstNumber = Float.parseFloat(calScreen.getText());
        OP = "+";
        numberClick += 1;
        if (!calScreen.getText().equals("+") && numberClick == 2){
            btEqual.doClick();
        }
        else {
            calScreen.setText("+");
        }


    }                                      

    private void btMinusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // minus button
        firstNumber = Float.parseFloat(calScreen.getText());
        OP = "-";
        numberClick += 1;
        if (!calScreen.getText().equals("-") && numberClick == 2){
            btEqual.doClick();
        }
        else {
            calScreen.setText("-");
        }
    }                                       

    private void btMultiActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // Multiply
        firstNumber = Float.parseFloat(calScreen.getText());
        OP = "*";
        numberClick += 1;
        if (!calScreen.getText().equals("x") && numberClick == 2){
            btEqual.doClick();
        }
        else {
            calScreen.setText("x");
        }
    }                                       

    private void btDivideActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // divide button
        firstNumber = Float.parseFloat(calScreen.getText());
        OP = "/";
        numberClick += 1;
        if (!calScreen.getText().equals("/") && numberClick == 2){
            btEqual.doClick();
        }
        else {
            calScreen.setText("/");
        }    
    }                                        

    private void btAnsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // Answer button
        if (!anw.equals("noInputYet")){
        calScreen.setText(anw);
        }
    }                                     

    private void btSignActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // button Change sign

    }                                      

    private void btPiActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // precent button 

            prNumber = Double.parseDouble(calScreen.getText())/100;
            if (prNumber == (int)prNumber){
            calScreen.setText(Integer.toString((int)prNumber));
            anw = Integer.toString((int)prNumber); 
            result = (int)prNumber; 
              }//prNumber is integer
            else {calScreen.setText(Double.toString(prNumber));
              anw = Double.toString(prNumber);
              result = Float.parseFloat(Double.toString(prNumber));
              }// If prNumber is flaot


    }                                    

    private void ButtonAllClearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        // ALL clear button
        calScreen.setText("0");
        firstNumber = 0;
        secondNumber = 0;
        result = 0;
        numberClick = 0; 
        anw = "noInputYet";
    }                                              

    private void btPwOf2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // button power of 2 
        result = Float.parseFloat(calScreen.getText()) * Float.parseFloat(calScreen.getText());
        if (result == (int)result){
            calScreen.setText(Integer.toString((int)result));
            anw = Integer.toString((int)result); 
              }//prNumber is integer
            else {calScreen.setText(Float.toString(result));
              anw = Float.toString(result);
              }// If prNumber is flaot
    }                                       

    private void calScreenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // Screen of Calculator

    }
```

Comment: I'd suggest putting your wording prior to the code. It allows people to understand the context before looking at a bunch of, seemingly, pointless code. @lpratlong: punctuation helps with coding problems?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, it helps people answer questions.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils It helps to understand what he means. Because it's incomprehensible. The code does not matter if we do not understand what is his problem.

Comment: -1 If I put the "code" in my test-project I only get a lot of compile errors.

Comment: I think what you mean is grammar more than punctuation. Perhaps not, but keep in mind not everyone is a native English speaker.

Comment: i am so sorry for my bad English this is my first time here and i am still a fresh year student sorry but i dont know which part of code that contain the bug because so i copy the whole code that i think can be the error

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1XOoin_1gcfOUJGSlIySVFiZ3M/edit?usp=sharing i think it better for me sharing the whole file

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I am not an ENglish native speaker but I use punctuation to indicate where my phrase begins and where it finish. Anyway, this is not the subject here.

Comment: @lpratlong so sorry bro my brain is nearly explode when i posted that. i will try to make it more readable next time

Comment: @user3725086 Thx, and try to remove some code to let only the most relevant. Else it will discourage people to take a look on it :).

Comment: @lpratlong: then why'd you bring it up? "Anyway," you said "First thing to do to fix your problem: learn punctuation", which is implying the only possible way to fix op's problem is to learn proper English punctuation, which is also obviously not true.

Comment: Next time? There's an **edit** button available - you can make it more readable *this time*. You should really consider creating an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem without that huge mass of UI code obscuring the issue. Bear in mind that you (presumably) wrote that code, so you should know where various bits of logic are. We don't have that insight, so you're more likely to get help if you only give us the relevant code, and if you've expressed your problem in a clear and concise manner.

Comment: @JonK thank sorry for all the inconvenience already edit it. thank for all the info

Comment: Please edit questions carefully from next time. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your `btMinusActionPerformed` method:

```
private void btMinusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // minus button
    firstNumber = Float.parseFloat(calScreen.getText());
    OP = "-";
    numberClick += 1;
    if (!calScreen.getText().equals("-") && numberClick == 2){
        btEqual.doClick();
    }
    else {
        calScreen.setText("-"); // <- What does this do?
    }
}
```

Then take a look at the `btEqualActionPerformed` method:

```
private void btEqualActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // Result
    // What is getText() going to return if you pressed the minus button?
    secondNumber = Float.parseFloat(calScreen.getText());
    { ... } // Omitted for brevity
}
```

Follow that through logically and you'll notice that when you click the buttons for `1`, `-`, and `2`, you will read in `1` and `-2`. You're already storing the operand in `OP`, so what you'll do is `1 - (-2)`, which does actually equal `3`. Your problem is in `btMinusActionPerformed` - that's where you need to fix your code.

---

Additionally, your `operations` regular expression isn't quite correctly defined. You haven't escaped either the `-` or the `.`, so they aren't going to work in the way that you expect them to.

```
operations = "[+|\\-|x|/|0|\\.]",
//               ^         ^
// Note the escape characters at these two locations
```

That should make your regex work in the way you intended for it to work.

An alternative solution would be to remove:

```
calScreen.setText("-");
```

From your `btMinusActionPerformed` method (and the corresponding lines from the other three operator's methods), which would mean that the regex wasn't necessary.

Comment: calScreen.setText("-") this code is to make the calScreen - when i press the - button.

Comment: What is getText() going to return if you pressed the minus button? if i pressed the - button 2 time it will just show the result to the screen like the real calculator (the nomal one without sin or cos xD )

Comment: i already set the code calScreen.getText().matches(operations) to get rid of "-" and when ever i press the number the number will just be 2 it work for other button like "+" "*" "/" but not "-" and i dont know why

Comment: @user3725086 RE your first comment: *exactly*, now think about the implications of adding that `-` character to the text field that you then read in later.

Comment: As I said previously, you're already storing the fact that you're doing a subtraction operation in your `OP` variable. What you're effectively doing is parsing that `-` *twice*, once as an operator and once as part of the subsequent number. This is what the problem is - you should only be parsing that `-` *once*.

Comment: sorry for my bad english but i can't seem to understand the above cmt clearly xD

Comment: i know i can do this for the short way around but why calScreen.getText().matches(operations) didnt work for "-". it shouldn't be in the text field if the above code is work. it was working before until i add some new button but after i deleting it the problem still there

Comment: As an observation, you have `-` listed twice in that regex, you should only need it once. It will also only match if the *entire String* matches the pattern, which it probably never will.

Comment: i have remove the - that was twice in the regex but is still not working

Comment: No, it won't, because the *entire String* doesn't match the pattern. Think about the primary display of the Windows calculator, it doesn't **show you** which operator you clicked, it just remembers what it was. You're remembering the operator in the `OP` variable, so you don't need to show it to the user either. You should be able to remove the `else` from each of the four operator's `btXActionPerformed` methods without breaking anything. I suspect you'll find that it will also fix the multiplication and division buttons as well. I have a feeling they don't work either at the moment...

Comment: done it but is still the same i had tried on  multiplication and division it all work fine on plus too but not minus T_T

Comment: i tried to check the boolean of the code output.getText().matches(operations)
while operations = "[+|-|x|/|0|.]" 
all of them show true only "-" but i can't seem the explain why

Comment: Your regex fails to match because you haven't escaped the `-` or the `.` properly (they're meaningful characters in a regular expression). You could change the regex to `[+|\\-|x|/|0|\\.]`, or you could remove the `.setText()` calls from the operator action methods. Which you do is up to you.

Comment: ok i fixed it  @JonK thx men for the help men u saved my life

Comment: @user3725086 If either of the answers here were helpful, you should *upvote* them as a way of indicating that to others. *Accepting* an answer also indicates to others that it solved your particular problem. Doing so is entirely up to you however (but considered good practice if your problem *was* solved).

Comment: my reputation was still so low that i can't upvote yet but i will when i got more reputation

Answer (score 0):

Here you set the minus in the textfield.

```
private void btMinusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { // minus button 
    firstNumber = Float.parseFloat(calScreen.getText()); 
    OP = "-"; 
    numberClick += 1; 
    if (!calScreen.getText().equals("-") && numberClick == 2){ 
      btEqual.doClick(); 
    } else { 
      calScreen.setText("-"); 
    } 
}
```

and later if you call `calScreen.getText());` you got the minus value back.
So remove the

```
calScreen.setText("-");
```

And it should work.

Comment: i set it so when i press the minus it will show on the screen and i already calScreen.getText().matches(operations) to prevent the - to get inside the number but i guess the code didnt work but i can't see why it didnt work

Comment: but you do not remove the operation before `btEqualActionPerformed` is called.

Comment: `code`if (calScreen.getText().matches(operations)) {
            calScreen.setText("2");}`code`

Comment: i add this so that if it were true it will will set calScreen to  2 and remove the -